# How to avoid closing of Overlay when a large SelectOnemenu inside it is clicked

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces

I have a `p:overlay` component which has a `h:selectOneMenu` inside it.
Data inside `h:selectOneMenu` is pretty lengthy so it expands out of the `p:overlay`.
So as you know when you click anywhere outside `p:overlay` then it closes.
Since my `h:selectOneMenu` expands out of the `p:overlay`, when I select a option which is out of `p:overlay`, its closing out.
How to avoid the closing of `p:overlay`?

Answer (score 1):

This is resolved in Primefaces 4. Set the attribute of overlayPanel dismissable="false"

```
<h:form id="email-form" style="margin-top:0.7em;">
    <p:commandButton id="removeBtn" value="Delete" type="button" />
    <p:overlayPanel for="removeBtn" dismissable="false">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
            <p:selectOneMenu id="select-one-subject" value="#{jobDetailMB.deleteEmailSubjectString}" >
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Email Subject" itemDisabled="true" />
                <f:selectItems value="#{jobDetailMB.supportService.findEmailSubjects()}" />
                <p:ajax />
            </p:selectOneMenu>
            <p:commandButton value="Delete Subject" action="#{jobDetailMB.deleteEmailSubject}" update=":email-form"  />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </p:overlayPanel>
</h:form>
```